# Query to copy from Sheet A to B based on TRUE/false

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to copy data from Sheet A to Sheet B based on if one of the columns has TRUE or False.

I'm trying to use:

```
=QUERY( 'A'!A1:I200 , "select * where I = 'True'" )
```

but this only gives me the header row.

How can I get it to copy all rows that contain TRUE?

Answer (score 2):

Use the formula below, in stead.

### Formula

```
=QUERY('A'!A1:I200 , "SELECT * WHERE I = TRUE")
```